# Very Simple Universal Covering problem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A space $X$ is constructed from two disjoint copies of $RP^3$ and a copy
of the unit interval $I$ by gluing one end of $I$ to a point of one copy of
$RP^3$, and gluing the other end of $I$ to the other copy of $RP^3.$

Would the Universal cover be the wedge product of two $3-spheres$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or would it be 2 3-spheres connected at 2 different points by 2 lines?

Comment: I am pretty certain on this answer.  Anyone else think this is right?

Comment: It certainly can't be the wedge sum of two spheres; what would cover the interval?

Comment: @Susan: A cover is given by 2 copies of $S^3$ connected by a pair of lines at antipodal points on the sphere. However, the fundamental group of this space is nontrivial, so it cannot be the universal cover. You can lift this idea a little further to find the universal cover.

Comment: It would actually be the infinite wedge of 3-spheres.